# WSO2 ESB to invoke secured web service deployed on weblogic

Tags: web-services, wso2, rampart, wso2-esb

How do one invoke a secured SOAP web service deployed on weblogic using WSO2 ESB ? Example's given in the tutorial seems to work only for secured web services deployed on Axis 2 server, using Apache Rampart.

Please guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It won't make any difference whether its developed in Axis2 or not. If you want to invoke a secured service through WSO2 ESB you need to attach the corresponding security policy to the end point.If you can share any errors you get with that approach that be helpful to answer better.

Comment: I did, I attached a policy when registering the endpoint, created request using XSLT (request creation here does not include wsse:Security header). The send mediator calls the endpoint, it successfully executes the Password Callback handler attached to the security policy. Finally it throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Missing wsse:Security header in request. I'm stuck here.